# Full text search api not working with objectify java : index.put() throwing nosuchmethod

Tags: java, google-app-engine, full-text-search, objectify

This is simple code for search api java , creating only one document and adding into an Index

we are using app engine java sdk 1.7.6 and objectify4.0 beta 1

the same code works when deployed online ,but not on localhost

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;



import com.google.appengine.api.search.Document;
import com.google.appengine.api.search.Field;
import com.google.appengine.api.search.Index; 
import com.google.appengine.api.search.IndexSpec;
import com.google.appengine.api.search.PutException;
import com.google.appengine.api.search.Results;
import com.google.appengine.api.search.ScoredDocument;
import com.google.appengine.api.search.SearchException;
import com.google.appengine.api.search.SearchService;
import com.google.appengine.api.search.SearchServiceFactory;
import com.google.appengine.api.search.StatusCode;



public class Search extends HttpServlet{ 
/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
        throws IOException, ServletException {

    res.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out = res.getWriter();

    String query=req.getParameter("query");
    out.println("<h1> this is the search query is="+query+"</h1>");







     SearchService searchService = SearchServiceFactory.getSearchService();
     Index indexe = searchService.getIndex(
              IndexSpec.newBuilder().setName("indexName").build());






    Document doc = Document.newBuilder()
            .setId("docid")
            .addField(Field.newBuilder().setName("id").setNumber(111.1))
            .addField(Field.newBuilder().setName("info").setText("hello"))
            .addField(Field.newBuilder().setName("service").setText("hello is the")).build();



     try {
        // Put the document.
            // here  nosuchmethod error comnes
        indexe.put(doc);

    } catch (PutException e) {
        if (StatusCode.TRANSIENT_ERROR.equals(e.getOperationResult().getCode())) {
            // retry putting the document

        }
    }

    try {
        // Query the index.
        Results<ScoredDocument> results = indexe.search("service name:"+query);

        for (ScoredDocument document : results) {

            // Use the document for display.
            List<Field>rs=  document.getExpressions();
            int t=0;
            while(t<rs.size())
            {
                Field f=rs.get(t);
                out.println(f.getText());
                t++;
            }
        }
    } catch (SearchException e) {
        if (StatusCode.TRANSIENT_ERROR.equals(e.getOperationResult().getCode())) {
            // retry
        }
    }


}
}
```

The problem is when document is put in index.
This is the block in which NoSuchMethod error is thrown.

```
 try {
        // Put the document.
            // here  nosuchmethod error comnes
        indexe.put(doc);

    } catch (PutException e) {
        if (StatusCode.TRANSIENT_ERROR.equals(e.getOperationResult().getCode())) {
            // retry putting the document

        }
    }
```

Below is the error returned by Index.put() method

```
HTTP ERROR 500

Problem accessing /Search. Reason:



com.google.appengine.api.search.Index.put([Lcom/google/appengine/api/search/Document;)
Lcom/ google/appengine/api/search/PutResponse;
Caused by:java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:                                                                          com.google.appengine.api.search.Index.put([Lcom/google/appengine/api/search/
    Document;Lcom/google/appengine/api/search/PutResponse;
at microService.Search.doGet(Search.java:77)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
at com.googlecode.objectify.cache.AsyncCacheFilter.doFilter(AsyncCacheFilter.java:59)
at com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyFilter.doFilter(ObjectifyFilter.java:49)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.api.socket.dev.DevSocketFilter.doFilter(DevSocketFilter.java:74)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You may be more likely to get an answer if you can isolate your problem to a smaller block of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also faced the same problem.The problem was not with objectify but with conflicting versions of jars in the library. Due to this the No such method error was thrown.
If you have different versions of same jars in the library, just delete the one you are not using.
I had two versions of appengine-api-sdk in the lib folder, deleting the one which I was not using solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is an excellent framework for full text search on Google app engine. The framework makes it simple to convert POJO's to searchable documents.

http://www.vidolima.com/projects/doco/

Comment: Does it have a maven repo? I can't find it